# C++ which template would be call if both template function match the argument list

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution, template-argument-deduction, partial-ordering

```
template<class T>
void fn(T t){}

template<class T>
void fn(std::vector<T> vt){}

void f() {
std::vector<int> vt;
fn(vt);
}
```

I know that the second template function would be called, but i dont know the rules for template function matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Partial ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Function_template_overloading) takes place in the overload resolution for a call to a function template specialization.

> Informally "A is more specialized than B" means "A accepts fewer types than B".

For this case, the 2nd `fn` is more specialized and wins in overload resolution, because it accepts types of instantiations of `std::vector` that is fewer than the 1st one, which could accept all the types.